# ImportError at / cannot import name Truncator

Tags: python, django, makefile, virtualenv, buildout

So I've setup old python project that uses django 1.3 with zc.buildout. When I run the server I get the following error:

Here's full stacktrace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['filebrowser',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'sugar',
 'registration',
 'webtopay',
 'pagination',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'mptt',
 'feincms',
 'feincms.module.page',
 'esavadai',
 'esavadai.documents',
 'esavadai.users',
 'esavadai.bookmarks',
 'esavadai.services',
 'esavadai.statistics',
 'esavadai.orders',
 'esavadai.emails',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions',
 'test_utils']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/eggs/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/eggs/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/project/esavadai/urls.py" in <module>
  8. admin.autodiscover()
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/eggs/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  26.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/eggs/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/eggs/django_extensions-1.3.9-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/admin/__init__.py" in <module>
  23. from django_extensions.admin.widgets import ForeignKeySearchInput
File "/home/marijus/workspace/esavadai/eggs/django_extensions-1.3.9-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/admin/widgets.py" in <module>
  7. from django.utils.text import Truncator

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name Truncator
```

Here's my buildout file:

```
[buildout]
parts =
    apacheconf
    production.py
    my.cnf
    mkdir
    django
#   scribd-patch
    jquery-ui
    tinymce

eggs =
    PIL
    South
    django
    django-annoying
    django-sugar
    python-scribd
    django-mptt
    django-filebrowser-no-grappelli
    django-webtopay
    django-pagination
    django-registration
    feincms
    mock
    simplejson
    djangorestframework
    djangorestframework-csv
    markdown

extra-paths = project


allowed-eggs-from-site-packages =
    PIL
    setuptools
    distribute

extensions = mr.developer
sources = sources
sources-dir = parts
auto-checkout = *

download-cache = cache

versions = versions

servername = www.myproject.com
serveradmin = admin@myproject.com

[sources]
# my.package = svn http://example.com/svn/my.package/trunk
# some.other.package = git git://example.com/git/some.other.package.git
# bzr.package = bzr bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~user/project/branch/
python-scribd = svn http://python-scribd.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
django-annoying = hg https://bitbucket.org/sirex/django-annoying
django-sugar = git git://github.com/montylounge/django-sugar.git
django-filebrowser-no-grappelli = git git://github.com/wardi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli.git
django-webtopay = git git://github.com/Motiejus/django-webtopay.git

[versions]
South = 0.7.3
django = 1.3
django-mptt = 0.4.2
django-pagination = 1.0.7
django-registration = 0.8
feincms = 1.4.2
mock = 0.8.0
simplejson = 2.2.1
djangorestframework = 2.2.7
markdown = 2.3.1
django-debug-toolbar = 0.9.4

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
project = project
settings = production
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = ${buildout:extra-paths}
wsgi = true
wsgilog = ${buildout:directory}/var/log/wsgi.log

[mkdir]
recipe = z3c.recipe.mkdir
paths =
    ${buildout:directory}/var/htdocs/static
    ${buildout:directory}/var/log

[apacheconf]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:directory}/etc/apache.conf.in
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/apache.conf

[production.py]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:directory}/etc/production.py.in
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/production.py

[my.cnf]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:directory}/etc/my.cnf.in
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/my.cnf

[scribd-patch]
recipe = collective.recipe.patch
path = parts/python-scribd/scribd/
patches = patches/scribd-issue-3.diff

[jquery-ui]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-1.8.19.zip
destination = ${buildout:directory}/var/vendor-staticfiles
ignore-existing = true
excludes =
    index.html
    development-bundle/*

[tinymce]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/archive/3.4.4.zip
destination = ${buildout:directory}/var/vendor-staticfiles
ignore-existing = true
excludes =
    tinymce/changelog.txt
    examples/*
strip-top-level-dir = true
```

From what I see Truncator class in django.utils.text is not in django 1.3. If I had to guess some module, whose version wasn't specified in buildout uses this class but didn't when this project was built on django 1.3.

Am I right ? Whether or not - what are my options here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Truncator class was added to Django 1.4. Evidently the version of django-extensions you installed requires Django 1.4 or newer; it is that package that tries to make this import.

You'll have to find and older version of that package that will work with your Django 1.3 setup.

Looking at the django-extensions GitHub repo you can see that they [removed compatibility for older Django versions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/commit/03dbda20ad6277ddebc466d55d3e812e2e247803) in November last year. The GitHub UI shows us that the earliest tag that contains that commit is 1.3, so the version before that should still work. That version appears to be 2.5, according to the GitHub tags list and the [django-extensions PyPI information](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extensions).

Pin that package in your versions section:

```
[versions]
# ...

django-extensions = 1.2.5
```